# Remove small icons alongside text (Every thing without icon)

Tags: windows-8, icons, themes

How do I remove the programme icons from menus, including Navigation pane.

```
 The Original theme is look like this:
```

[image]

```
 And it is what I want like this
```

[image]

My theme is in high contrast mode.

I know two .dll file that stored all icons, are `imageres.dll` and `shell32.dll` in `C:\windows\system32\HERE` and I can replace all icons with new icons by using `Resource Hacker` tool, BUT it only allow me to replace one icon with one another. Is any way to replace one with all of that at a time?

Comment: Your question is hard to understand. Please [edit] it to be more details of what version of Windows and what you are trying to do. Also, include what you've tried so far.

Comment: You can go for a transparent icon everywhere theme.

Answer (score 0):

If you can't find an option to remove it, you can always try the hard way.

Make sure to save your *registry hives* before applying this !

Locate your Local Machine Folder and go into Policy or Microsoft -> Windows. Locate something that could be a key that is tied with your function.

Edit to 0 if it is a single value key. If it's longer, you should search on Tech Sites.

HKEY Current Config is also known to hold the Keys responsible for the GUI.

**Short answer** : a solution you could check for is registry as you don't delete any files or install anything. I have did a few Registry tweaking in the past to control my menu in desktop or add shortcuts to my batch scripts. Registry have been also useful to fix extensions error.

Technet is a Windows Resource but Sites like LifeHacker or How-to-Geek feature many hacks or tweaks related with registry. Running a search on those sites could yield results. It is late so I can contribute more tomorrow by searching for a registry fix for you.

---

New answer !

"Removing a program icon from the Start menu doesn't remove it from the All Programs list or uninstall the program.

Click the Start button Picture of the Start button.
Right-click the program icon you want to remove from the Start menu, and then click Remove from this list."

From Windows 8 Help page. 
It was found there : http://windows.microsoft.com/en-ca/windows-vista/customize-the-start-menu

Here is a tutorial :

http://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/265-start-menu-customize.html

It includes 2 solutions with many steps. I can't include all the text in the post.

```
1. Right click on the Start button and click on Properties.


2. 1. Open the Start Menu, then type regedit in the search box and press Enter. 

2. 2. HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\Advanced

2. 3. Read the instructions for which keys you can modify/create. There are links to   
      similar topics in bottom.
```

Comment: I don't understand your answer! please tell me more.

Comment: Most options can be done through some options that can be done through clicking. Saving your registry is important to rollback if you edit the wrong key. If you want to remove programs icon menus, you would have to remove all icons, not just the *Featured* Programs. There is a Switch to Enable/Disable Options like that. Nothing more. If it's not there, creating a D-Word key would help. Give me time to search for my registry... :)

Comment: Your answer is not for my question. Did you read my question? I am windows 8 user and this picture is Navigation panel not Start menu that I mentioned in body of my question. -1

Answer (score 0):

If you could not find a solution, you can always try this, too :

You can change all the icons with a blank one
(Can make a 1 pixel blank gif for this).

[And this may also be helpful to you.](http://www.askvg.com/how-to-remove-program-icons-from-windows-titlebar-and-taskbar-buttons/)

Comment: Sorry. If you have time, you might change all icons by hand with an empty one (as my first remommendation.) Or you can find an application that changes icons, so you can easily change with the empty one.

Comment: I don't think so, you should replace one by one, imho.

Comment: Thanks, I accepted your answer but you just delete last recommendation. it's not useful any more. and also all icons has .ico not .gif. and delete 1 pixel because  windows doesn't allow icons smaller than 16*16 size

Comment: I mean you should create a transparent icon, by using 1 pixel (and yes, it should be in size of 16x16). I think that you can create a transparent icon using Fireworks or Photoshop.

Comment: Could you create the transparent icon ? If not, I can create that for you, and may give you a download address, here.

Comment: If you have time, I'd be happy to do this for me. thank you.

Comment: Okey no problem.

Comment: You can try this : http://hqtunes.com/blank16x16.ico  To do this: I have created a 16x16 pixel transparent png on Fireworks and converted it to 16x16 pixel icon on this page : http://www.prodraw.net/favicon/generator.php I have tested, its nice but it become black on some sizes.

Comment: oh no, then it's not useful. however thank you so much, guy.

Comment: Okey but what's the problem ? You're welcome.